# Log Log Probability Chart in R

Tags: r, power-law, ecdf

I'm sure this is easy, but I've been tearing my hair out trying to find out how to do this in R.

I have some data that I am trying to fit to a power law distribution. To do this, you need to plot the data on a log-log cumulative probability chart. The y-axis is the LOG of the frequency of the data (or log-probability, if you like), and the x-axis is the log of the values. If it's a straight line, then it fits a power law distribution, and the gradient determines the power law parameter.

If I want the frequency of the data, I can just use the ecdf() function:

My data set is called Profits.negative, and it's just a long list of trading profits that were less than zero (and I've notionally converted them all to positive numbers to avoid logging problems later on).

So I can type

```
plot(ecdf(Profits.negative))
```

And I get a handy empirical CDF function plotted. All I need to do is to convert both axes to log scales. I can do the x-axis:

```
Profits.negative.logs <- log(Profits.negative)
plot(ecdf(Profits.negative.logs))
```

Almost there! I just need to work out how to log the y-axis! But I can't seem to do it, and I can't work out how to extract the figures from the ecdf object. Can anyone help?

I know there is a power.law.fit function, but that just estimates the parameters - I want to plot the data and see if it lines up.

Comment: You'll likely get more help by including the data you're working with.  This post is helpful in that regard: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/495372

Answer (score 6):

You can fit and plot power-laws using the [poweRlaw](https://github.com/csgillespie/poweRlaw) package. Here's an example. First we generate some data from a heavy tailed distribution:

```
set.seed(1)
x = round(rlnorm(100, 3, 2)+1)
```

Next we load the package and create a data object and a displ object:

```
library(poweRlaw)
m = displ$new(x)
```

We can estimate `xmin` and the scaling parameter:

```
est = estimate_xmin(m))
```

and set the parameters

```
m$setXmin(est[[2]])
m$setPars(est[[3]])
```

Then plot the data and add the fitted line:

```
plot(m)
lines(m, col=2)
```

To get:

[image]

Comment: this is really useful. I'm trying to manually replicate your plot something similar to rafa's solution below. How could I view the source code for `m` above (what exactly goes in for x and y in `plot(m)`), I would like to see the equivalent of rafa's `k <- seq_along(x)` in your code if possible? `getAnywhere(displ)` doesnt show me. I'm trying to figure out why he (you too?) use `k` rather than log(x) on the x axis? Thanks

Comment: If you do `dd = plot(m)` you get back the x and y. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Data generation first (*you part, actually ;*)):

```
set.seed(1)
Profits.negative <- runif(1e3, 50, 100) + rnorm(1e2, 5, 5)
```

Logging and `ecdf`:

```
Profits.negative.logs <- log(Profits.negative)
fn <- ecdf(Profits.negative.logs)
```

`ecdf` returns function, and if you want to *extract* something from it - it's good idea to look into function's closure:

```
ls(environment(fn))
# [1] "f"      "method" "n"      "nobs"   "x"      "y"      "yleft"  "yright"
```

Well, now we can access `x` and `y`:

```
x <- environment(fn)$x
y <- environment(fn)$y
```

Probably it's what you need. Indeed, `plot(fn)` and `plot(x,y,type="l")` show virtually the same results. To log y-axis you need just:

```
plot(x,log(y),type="l")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

# data
  set.seed(1)
  x = round(rlnorm(100, 3, 2)+1)

# organize data into a df
  df <- data.frame(x = sort(x, decreasing = T),
                   pk <- ecdf(x)(x),
                   k <- seq_along(x))

# plot
  ggplot(df, aes(x=k, y= pk)) + geom_point(alpha=0.5) + 
    coord_trans(x = 'log10', y = 'log10') +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```

[image]

Comment: why do you plot log(k) `seq_along(x)` on the x axis and not log(x) if you are trying to plot a log log plot? See my comment above under Colins answer. Thanks